# Textarea height: 100%

Tags: html, css

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e6kCH/15/

It may sound stupid, but I can't find a way to make the text area height equal to 100%. It works for the width, but not for height.

I want the text area to resize depending of the window size...like it works in my fiddle for the width...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

**Height of an element is relative to its parent.** Thus, if you want to make expand your element into the whole height of the viewport, you need to apply your CSS to `html` and `body` as well (the parent elements):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#textbox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Alternative solution with CSS3**: If you can use CSS3, you can use [Viewport percentage units](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) and directly scale your textbox to 100 % height (and 100% width) of the viewport [(jsfiddle here)](http://jsfiddle.net/A22SF/)

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#textbox {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Viewport does the job!