# I am creating a chrome app to edit pure text, and i am using a <textarea> to accomplish this. It will not go full size

Tags: html, css, json, google-chrome-app

So I am creating a chrome app, and i have used the CSS in a post that some other guy asked. I am using a textarea to accomplish this. I do not mind any alternatives to a textarea. I am trying to get the textarea to stay the same size of the window.

I included [his question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089540/textarea-height-100) below.

I cannot get the `textarea` to stay aligned with the window border. I am trying to make this app a text editor, and would like the app to be as convenient as possible. I have a link to the app below. As of now, it is functional, but the textarea's size will have to be manually changed.

I do not want this.

[Chrome App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text-edity/alaaajbhfhbpghccbjklfmgknnehhhpc)

Also I would like to add a save to disk button that cannot be edited, and stays in the bottom right corner. I do not know how to do this, and some help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the manifest.json file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Text Edity",
  "short_name": "TextEdity",
  "description": "A simple text editor, does nothing but edit text!",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "38",

   "icons": {
    "16": "assets/icon_16.png",
    "128": "assets/icon_128.png"
  },

  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried this js, but it does not work, and if there were the save button, the  user would be able to edit it, and delete it.

```
document.body.contentEditable='true';document.designMode='on';void 0;
```

The HTML:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>Text Edity</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="text.png">
 </head>  
 <body>
  <textarea cols='95' rows='44' placeholder='Text Edity'></textarea>
 </body>
</html>`
```

And the background.js:

```
/**
 * Listens for the app launching, then creates the window.
 *
 * @see http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app.runtime.html
 * @see http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app.window.html
 */
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {
  chrome.app.window.create(
    'index.html',
    {
      id: 'mainWindow',
      bounds: {width: 800, height: 800}
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: show your code or work

Comment: OK, so that's the other guy's question; what is yours?

Comment: your right, sorry im gonna do that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS like:

```
textarea {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

you can even use it inline in the element like:

```
<textarea cols='95' rows='44' placeholder='Text Edity' style='position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;'></textarea>
```

The button can be achieved the same way:

```
<button style='position: absolute; bottom: 10px; right: 10px; z-index: 1;'>Save</button>
```

The `z-index` is mandatory only if you place `button` **before** `textarea`, if you place it after you don't have to use it.

Comment: vlgalik thx for the positioning on the button but i also do not know how to actually save the content, sorry im not too good with css and simalar languages.

Comment: thank you, that worked very well! also, the way you said took away the odd looking texterea "borders"/edges, thx

Comment: @tyler-richardson The saving part is done by JavaScript using [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) or [Storage APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_storage)